# Google play console Closed Testing link sent to accepted testers taking infinite time load the the app. (React native)

Tags: react-native, google-play-console

I uploaded an app a react native app on google play console for closed testing. The release was approved and I followed the steps to add testers inside closed testing and send them the join from the android link on their email. One of them was my own for testing.

Whenever I am clicking on the link it is taking an infinite time to load the app. And the app is not going to the download page on the Google play store where it is supposed to take me.

Is this a usual problem does it always takes that much time. Or I am missing anything here.